# Simple or comparison doesn't work, undefined function ()?

Tags: php

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function  () in
>   /home/gmfeedsc/domains/cekdahl.com/public_html/virek/system/application/views/rekommendationer/visa.php
>   on line 263

And that row is:

```
<?php if ( ($post['users_id'] == $this->userId) || ($this->userLevel > 0) ): ?>
```

And I can't figure it out. I guess it is because it thinking ( ) around the comparison is a function, but how else could I write this? thanks.

EDIT:
My script is a Codeigniter view, and the surrounding code is only XHTML. Since practice mandates that I shouldn't retrieve variables by $this-> in the view, I made them variables instead and the code looks like this now:

```
<?php if ( ($post['users_id'] == $userId) || ($userLevel > 0) ): ?>
```

These statements work independently, the problem arises when I put them together.

Comment: Why do you have `:` at the end of the `if` statement?

Comment: @Justin: because it is another (alternate) `if` statement syntax

Comment: @Calle: post please more code. btw this line **cannot** throw such error

Comment: I would first try removing one, then the other comparison operators and see if each work independently.

Comment: @zerkms: I've learnt something today ;-)

Comment: Yes, they work individually. There is no more code to this, really. This is MVC (Codeigniter), and around that line is only xhtml.

Comment: @zerkms: Cool, thanks for pointing that out. PHP can be such a quirky language...

Comment: btw, this fatal error doesn't hinder the output of the page. It just prints this error and nothing seems to be affected (except the comparison doesn't work, obviously). Kind of strange.

Comment: I'd specifically be interested in code __before__ the if statement. PHP isn't always super reliable about line numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this code. However, try writing it like this:

```
if ($post['users_id'] == $userId or $userLevel > 0)
```

If you are still having issues, try nested ifs to see if you get the same result:

```
if ($post['user_id'] == $userId) {
    if ($userLevel > 0) {
```

Comment: that would be a -1 if I had any votes left for suggesting the unnecessary nested ifs (ugghh) instead of solving the problem

Comment: somehow the first suggestion actually worked!! Of course nested ifs won't work though. I agree with aaronasterling about that: it doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: I agree... I hate if. If you reread my comment, I am suggesting it be tried to see if Calle get's the same results. Sorry if you took it to imply it would be a "good" solution. But the base solution is to remove the additional unneeded parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have no
    `<?php endif; ?>` after your conditional (XHTML) action.

(see [the PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).)